# rails asset pipeline clarifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Just a few questions to clarify some confusing factors for me.

About application.js:

1. `require_tree .` will recursively include all the js files within `app/assets/javascripts`. If I put a javascript file in `app/assets/javascripts/subfolder`, it will be included. If I just want to include a specific directory, I should use `require_directory`
2. `lib/assets/javascripts` and `vendor/assets/javascripts` can be referenced from the manifest, `application.js`. Their javascript files WILL NOT be precompiled unless they are stated in the manifest.
3. When I install a gem that requires a set of javascripts(e.g. bootstrap) I require the related javascripts files in the manifest too (e.g. `//= require bootstrap`). The javascript files live in the Gem path, and they can be referenced by relative paths too.

Are my statements all true?

Answer (score 0):

For sure I can say that 1 & 3 are true, I use both of those statements in my code.
When it comes to numer 2, as Rails Asset Pipeline docs says:

> For example, these files:
>
> ```
>   app/assets/javascripts/home.js
>   lib/assets/javascripts/moovinator.js
>   vendor/assets/javascripts/slider.js
> ```
>
> would be referenced in a manifest like this:
>
> ```
>   //= require home
>   //= require moovinator
>   //= require slider
> ```

[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)